I do not know what my problem is called exactly, how do I represent criteria arrangements in parentheses (image for clarification)

I have established three criteria in the previous paragraph: the first one, the second one and the third one.
In the given image, (1st/2nd/3rd) stands for “who fulfilled the first, second, and third criteria”, (1st/2nd/_) stands for “who fulfilled the first and second criteria, but not the third and so on and so forth.
I wanted to know if there is already a way to do this that had already been done.

It would be better if you could present text as text (and not as an image), because some people on the internet cannot see images.

Your question is how to present data.
Without your explanation your presentation would be incomprehensible. A common way to write this would be something like "... fulfilled all three criteria, ... fulfilled the first and second criteria, ... fullfilled the second and third criteria, ... fulfilled the first criterion, and ... fulfilled the second."
Another way would be to present the information in a table:
Group(s)          Criteria
                  1    2    3
Greek Melkites    x    x    x
Semi-Barbarians   x    x
Persians               x    x
Arab Melkites     x
Greek Syriacs          x


I was looking to find a way to write it consisely, because I have used parentheses like that often in my text but in hindsight I might have used them too much.

I think the table would be easier for people to hold in their heads.

Yeah, a table is the only practical way to approach what im trying to do. Anything else wouldnt be clear enouch. I dont wanna make whatever im talking about even more complicated than it already is. @KateGregory
